# Effect of pH on volatility (odor) of organic acid

Tags: acid-base, ions, smell

Based on two assumptions:

- Ionic solutes can generally be considered nonvolatile
- As the pH of a solution of organic acid is increased, an increasing percentage of it is deprotonated, or *ionized* (Henderson-Hasselbach eqn).

I think I should be able to decrease the volatility of an organic acid solution by increasing pH. However, in several rough experiments with acetic acid, I don't observe a very strong reduction in odor with increasing pH. Even a theoretically neutralized solution retains a significant vinegar odor.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for unanswered questions about it that still remain.

Answer (score 1):

Acetic acid is a weak acid (pKa 4.8). Even if you neutralize it, some acetate ions will react with water to form acetic acid and hydroxide ion (hydrolysis). Since acetic acid has a quite strong smell, we are able to detect its presence in neutral acetate solutions. If you will increase pH to a high value with a strong base, the concentration of acetic acid will drop (Le Châtelier's principle).